# Is this simple layout achievable in css Grid?

Tags: css, css-grid

I have three divs containing text, a quote and images. I want the images on the right. The text and quote on the left. With the quote immediately below the text.

[image]

This is easy to achieve using floats. But I'd like to use Grid (because at smaller screen sizes the three elements will work to a different grid / layout).

Unfortunately grid is putting the third element - the quote - in a new row. This row sits below the row containing the text and images.

So is the layout possible in CSS grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine a grid with a flex-box. So you can be sure that the quote is always displayed below the text.

**Edit:** You could also archieve this using pure grid without a flexbox. For this you have to edit the `grid-template-areas`. But I would recommend to use the solution below because with this you have less trubble to fit it into a responsive design.

```css
.grid{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 100%; 
    grid-template-columns: 50% 50%; 
    grid-template-areas:  
    "text image"; 
    grid-column-gap: 8px;
    background: #dedede;
}

.text-wrapper{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    grid-area: text;
    background: #aaa;
}

.text-wrapper .text{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: justify;
}

.text-wrapper .quote{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 28px;
}

.image-wrapper{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    background: #aaa;
    grid-area: image;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.image-wrapper .image{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
    <div class="text-wrapper">
    <span class="text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
    </span>
    <span class="quote">"Hello World"</span>
    </div>
    <div class="image-wrapper">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="image">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="image">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="image">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. That answered my question